# SCons custom builder - build with multiple files and output one file

Tags: builder, scons

If I have an executable that generates an output from multiple files at a time -

```
generate_output -o a.out -f input1.txt input2.txt input3.txt
```

Is there a way to write such a custom builder for this?
What I have at the moment is -

```
builder = Builder(
        action='generate_output -o $TARGET -f $SOURCE',
        suffix='.out', src_suffix='.txt')
```

Then it only generates files in a sequence, which is not what I really wanted -

```
generate_output -o input1.out -f input1.txt
generate_output -o input2.out -f input2.txt
# etc...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using `$SOURCES`, see [Variable Substitution](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html#lbAS):

```
builder = Builder(
        action='generate_output -o $TARGET -f $SOURCES',
        suffix='.out', src_suffix='.txt')
```

It works for me in this simple example:

```
env = Environment()

builder = Builder(action='cat $SOURCES > $TARGET',
        suffix='.out', src_suffix='.txt')

env = Environment(BUILDERS = {'MyBld' : builder})

env.MyBld('all', ['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt'])
```

This will work as long as `generate_output` doesn't require `-f` to precede each input file.